# Hexadecimal notation and signed integers

Tags: c#, types, hex

This is a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319199/why-is-java-able-to-store-0xff000000-as-an-int). So, Java store's integers in [two's-complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and you can do the following:

```
int ALPHA_MASK = 0xff000000;
```

In C# this requires the use of an unsigned integer, `uint`, because it interprets this to be `4278190080` instead of `-16777216`.

My question, how do declare negative values in hexadecimal notation in c#, and how exactly are integers represented internally? What are the differences to Java here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

C# (rather, .NET) also uses the two's complement, but it supports both signed and unsigned types (which Java doesn't). A bit mask is more naturally an unsigned thing - why should one bit be different than all the other bits?

In this specific case, it is safe to use an unchecked cast:

```
int ALPHA_MASK = unchecked((int)0xFF000000);
```

To "directly" represent this number as a signed value, you write

```
int ALPHA_MASK = -0x1000000; // == -16777216
```

Hexadecimal is not (or should not) be any different from decimal: to represent a negative number, you need to write a negative sign, followed by the digits representing the absolute value.

Comment: "A bit mask is more naturally an unsigned thing - why should one bit be different than all the other bits?" -- Because it is not a bit mask. You can do those properly with an `enum` marked with `[Flags]` attribute.

Comment: "Hexadecimal is not (or should not) be any different from decimal" -- Bit it is different and it should be different, because hexadecimal is just a more convenient representation of binary numbers where the highest bit is a sign bit by convention, and negative numbers are written in 2's complement.

Comment: "to represent a negative number, you need to write a negative sign, followed by the digits representing the absolute value." -- That's not how you should write negative hexadecimal numbers. If you write `-0x8007052E` what do you expect to get? I would expect `0x7FF8FAD2`, because that would be the result of the CPU `NEG` instruction. C and C++ have solved this problem of a variable and a constant type matching decades ago by using suffixes `u` and `l`, but I guess taking a hint from there would have been too painful for C# designers' ego.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can use an unchecked block and a cast:

```
unchecked
{
    int ALPHA_MASK = (int)0xff000000;
}
```

or

```
int ALPHA_MASK = unchecked((int)0xff000000);
```

Not terribly convenient, though... perhaps just use a literal integer?

Comment: I had no idea C# had this keyword. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

And just to add insult to injury, this will work too:

```
-0x7F000000
```