# Setting ints to negative values using hexadecimal literals in C#

Tags: c#, hex, integer

Is there any way to set an `int` to a negative value using a hexadecimal literal in C#? I checked the specification on [Integer literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674.aspx) but it didn't mention anything.

For example:

```
int a = -1;         // Allowed
int b = 0xFFFFFFFF; // Not allowed?
```

Hexadecimal notation is clearer for my application, and I'd prefer not to use `uint`s because I would need to do some extra casting.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319993/c-hexadecimal-notation-and-signed-integers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hexadecimal notation and signed integers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319993/hexadecimal-notation-and-signed-integers-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the unchecked keyword.

```
unchecked
{
   int b = (int)0xFFFFFFFF;    
}
```

or even shorter

```
int b = unchecked((int)0xFFFFFFFF);
```

Answer (score 3):

i think you can use `-0x1` with c#

Comment: Yes, this is valid syntax, but having to do the negation in my head to figure out what the real value is is a bit tedious.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast it and put it in an unchecked context.

```
unchecked {
    int i = (int)0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get the job done without unchecked operations or casting.

```
int i = 0xFF << 24 | 0xFF << 16 | 0xFF << 8 | 0xFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Convert" class:

```
string hex = "FF7F";
int myInt = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
```