# C#, negative decimal values to heximal

Tags: c#, .net, hex, decimal

I'm writing a code which has to save up as much space as possible.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Code.Length; i++){
    CodeInHex[i] = String.Format("{0:X}", Code[i]); // e.g. Dec value = -95, hex = "FFFFFFA1"
}
```

Is there a way to make heximal value equal to -A1 instead of "FFFFFFA1"? (saw it is allowed in c# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120512/setting-ints-to-negative-values-using-hexadecimal-literals-in-c-sharp)).

Comment: "As much as possible" is not the same as "as much as convenient". My guess is, that "as much as possible" will lead to something quite complex.

Comment: btw; lots and lots of encoding formats exist for these things; another option that leaps to mind would be "zigzag varint encoding, as hex" - that would be `BD01` as hex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could do it manually:

```
var val = Code[i];
CodeInHex[i] = val < 0 ? ("-" + (-val).ToString("X")) : val.ToString("X");
```

But! Negative hex is not a common way of representing negative numbers. It is only "allowed in C#" because it is the unary negation operator applied to a positive constant; i.e. when the question shows `-0x1`, it is "negate (some expression)", where "some expression" is `0x1`.

Comment: If it is possible to make an own system representing numbers, then it would be wiser to use a much higher base on the numbers. For example, by using digits and upper and lower case alphabets could denote integers of base 62, which shortens the string representation significantly.

Comment: results in `-5F` instead of `-A1`

Comment: Could you comment on second line a little?

Comment: @SaebAmini yes, that is correct; `-A1` would be -161, not -95. The error here is the question, not the answer, IMO.

Comment: @Carl I edited it once already; can you clarify what comment topic you want?

Comment: @JoriO yes, that's fair; base-64 without padding might be a reasonable starting place.

Comment: @Marc Well if you do have time:
> val < 0 ? 
and 
 :
I can find it on the web anyway but if you could assist that would be great.

Comment: @JoriO like this (very hacky implementation, mainly to illustrate intent, not good practice): http://pastie.org/9624419

Comment: @Carl that is the conditional operator; `{cond} ? {A} : {B}` means "if {cond} is true, evaluate {A}, otherwise, evaluate {B}" - i.e. if the value is negative, use (a minus sign concatenated with the string representation of the absolute value, by negating it), else use (the string representation of the positive value).