# C# 7 binary literal for -1

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.0

I want to declare `-1` literal using the new binary literal feature:

```
int x = 0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

However, this doesn't work because C# considers this as a `uint` literal and we get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'uint' to 'int'...` which is a bit strange for me since we deal with binary data.

Is there a way to declare `-1` integer value using binary literal in C#?

Comment: I haven't got access to C# 7 to test this, but have you tried: int x = (int)0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111;

Comment: keyword is "implicitly" -- cast it?

Comment: *Why* do you want to declare `-1` and why do you care if it's an `int` or `uint`? An error code like an HRESULT for example is the same whether it's treated as an int or uint. The same holds for any bitfield value. What matters is the value of the individual bits. Saying that `negative values are errors` is actually an approximation for the real rule that `values with the highest bit set are errors`

Comment: See [Setting ints to negative values using hexadecimal literals in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120512/) and similar threads. This issue has been there all the time for hexadecimal literals. It is by design.

Comment: It does not make sense to do that... the representation of -1 change depending on the target type width.

Comment: @Phil1970 In a sense that is true for `+1` as well. The only difference is whether we fill up with ones or with zeroes.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen This is a big difference as you have to ensure you write all required 1's. You have to cover the whole width and if you change the type, you also need to update the value. You don't have such problem with unsigned integers.

Answer (score 4):

After trying some cases, I finally found out this one

```
int x = -0b000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0001;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

And as result is printed -1.

If I understand everything correct they use sing flag for -/+ so when you put 32 1 you go into uint

Answer (score 4):

You can explicitly cast it, but because there's a constant term involved, I believe you have to manually specify [`unchecked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked):

```
int x = unchecked((int)0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111);
```

(Edited to include Jeff Mercado's suggestion.)

You can also use something like `int x = -0b1` as pointed out in S.Petrosov's answer, but of course that doesn't show the actual bit representation of -1, which might defeat the purpose of declaring it using a binary literal in the first place.

Comment: You don't need an unchecked block, unchecked works for expressions as well. It'd be cleaner to do it as `int x = unchecked((int)0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111);`

Comment: Thanks, @JeffMercado! I should have remembered that. I guess it goes to show how often I use `unchecked`. :)

Comment: You can also cheat and say `int x = unchecked((sbyte)0b1111_1111);`; then you only have to type 8 ones.

Comment: Instead of unary `-`, it may be more clear to use the bitwise "flip" `~`, so that would be `int x = ~0b0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000;` or just `int x = ~0b0;` if you prefer.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen of you know, just write `int x = -1;` :)