# How do I convert ushort to short in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

One version is

```
short value = unchecked((short)0x8010);
```

Other versions like below will not work, and will throw an exceptions

```
short value = Convert.ToInt16(0x8010);
short value = (short)(0x8010);
```

Is there any other version without unchecked keyword?

**Updated**: expected is negative value of -32752

Comment: What output are you expecting? 0x8010 is greater than short.MaxValue, so are you expecting the error, or are you expecting the overflowed value?

Comment: 0x8010 is not unsigned short tho...

Comment: And according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), *The explicit numeric conversion may cause loss of precision or result in throwing exceptions.*

Comment: If you're looking for the negative value, you must use unchecked, otherwise you will get the exception.  See Anders' answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will work to convert all `ushort` values which fit into `short` and replace all values which don't with `short.MaxValue`.  This is lossy conversion though.

```
ushort source = ...;
short value = source > (ushort)short.MaxValue
  ? short.MaxValue
  : (short)source;
```

If you are looking for a straight bit conversion you can do the following (but I wouldn't recommend it)

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct EvilConverter
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] short ShortValue;
    [FieldOffset(0)] ushort UShortValue;

    public static short Convert(ushort source)
    {
        var converter = new EvilConverter();
        converter.UShortValue = source;
        return converter.ShortValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  I think the OP is looking for a C-style bit reinterpretation, which was never a good idea in the first place and rightfully does not work in C#.

Answer (score 7):

What do you expect `value` to be?

`0x8010 = 32784`

The range of a short is -32768 to 32767 so the value 32784 cannot be expressed by a short. A short stored as 0x8010 will be interpreted as a negative number. Is it that negative number you want?

According to another SO question [C#, hexadecimal notation and signed integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319993/c-hexadecimal-notation-and-signed-integers) the `unsafe` keyword must be used in this case in C# if you want it to be interpreted as a negative number.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how `unsafe` alters that behavior. Was trying to figure out why [BitConverter](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/BitConverter.cs#L106) is programmed the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
ushort input;
short output;
output = short.Parse(input.ToString("X"), NumberStyles.HexNumber));
```