# Any one tell me why we write this 0xff000000 in filters?

Tags: java, colors, rgb

Here is my code for GrayScale filter want to know about this

```
class GrayScale extends RGBImageFilter {
  @Override
    public int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
    int a = rgb & 0xff000000;
    int r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;
    int g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xff;
    int b = rgb & 0xff;
    rgb = (r * 77 + g * 151 + b * 28) >> 8; 
    return a | (rgb << 16) | (rgb << 8) | rgb;
    }
}
```

Comment: `rgb & 0xff000000` means that you apply a mask to your rgb color to get the alpha value of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The format of your input is `0xAARRGGBB` where `AA` is the alpha (transparency), `RR` is the red, `GG` is the green, and `BB` is the blue component. This is hexadecimal, so the values range from 00 to FF (255).

Your question is about the extraction of the alpha value. This line:

`int a = rgb & 0xFF000000`

If you consider a value like `0xFFFFFFFF` (white), `AND` will return whatever bits are set in both the original colour and the mask; so you'll get a value of `0xFF`, or 255 (correctly).

Comment: Thanks this line was confusing me too much now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
int a = rgb & 0xff000000;
...
return a | ...;
```

simply preserves the top 8 bits of `rgb` (which contain the [alpha component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Beside Ashes999 and NPE answers, if you want to know how it's treated internally in java, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319199/why-is-java-able-to-store-0xff000000-as-an-int)