# Why 0xff000000 is negative in Java?

Tags: java

```
FF000000=4278190080<2^(8*4)-1 (4 bytes)
```

but when I type in "`System.out.println(0xff000000);`"

it shows "`-16777216`". Why does it become negative in `java`?

Comment: please read on how java stores numbers in numeric variables..

Comment: Might be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319199/why-is-java-able-to-store-0xff000000-as-an-int

Comment: ok...my bad for posting duplicated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you have to know is how signed numbers are represented in java:
**FF000000** is a sigened number and if you convert it to binary will be something like **1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000**
now, the MSB is the sign bit, the rest is the number in 2's complement.

That means **FF000000**= -(00FFFFFF) in 2's complement, wich is -16777216.

More info about java [primitive Data](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) can be found here.