# write a hexadecimal integer literal equal to Int.MIN_VALUE in Kotlin

Tags: integer, hex, kotlin

how does one write a hexadecimal integer literal that is equal to `Int.MIN_VALUE` (which is `-2147483648` in decimal) in Kotlin?

AFAIK, an Int is 4 bytes...and sometimes it seems like [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is used to represent integers...but I'm not sure. I've tried the following hex literals to help myself understand the system:

- `0xFFFFFFFF` but this is a `Long`, not an `Int`
- `0xFFFFFFFF.toInt()` which is -1
- `-0xFFFFFFFF.toInt()` which is 1
- `0x7FFFFFFF` which is 2147483647 which is `Int.MAX_VALUE`
- `-0x7FFFFFFF` which is -2147483647 which is `Int.MIN_VALUE+1`
- `0xFFFFFFF` which is 268435455 in decimal
- `0x0FFFFFFF` which is also 268435455 in decimal

But I can't figure out what hexadecimal integer literal can be used to represent `Int.MIN_VALUE`.

I hope the answer doesn't make me feel stupid...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`Int`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/) represents a 32-bit signed integer. 32 bits means 8 hex digits:

`___7    F    F    F    F    F    F    F`

`0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`

As you can see the left-most bit is 0 thus this is a positive integral in a 32 bit representation. By [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) definition and example the minimal 32-bit negative value will have `1` at left-most bit followed by `0`:

`1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`

`___8    0    0    0    0    0    0    0`

that is `0x80000000`.

In Kotlin you need to prepend the `-` sign to denote negative `Int` which is not true in Java. Consider following example

```
println(0x7FFFFFFF) // -> prints 2147483647 (Integer.MAX_VALUE)
println(-0x80000000) // -> prints -2147483648 (Integer.MIN_VALUE)
println(0x80000000) // -> prints 2147483648 (does not fit into Int)
```

It's not the same as in Java:

```
System.out.println(0x7FFFFFFF); // -> prints 2147483647 (Integer.MAX_VALUE)
System.out.println(-0x80000000); // -> prints -2147483648 (Integer.MIN_VALUE)
System.out.println(0x80000000); // -> prints -2147483648 (Integer.MIN_VALUE)
```

This is in line with [Kotlin spec](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-spec/blob/release/docs/src/md/kotlin.core/expressions.md#decimal-integer-literals) although the overflow behavior of [hexadecimal literals is yet to be defined](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-spec/blob/release/docs/src/md/kotlin.core/expressions.md#hexadecimal-integer-literals).

Further reading:

- [Why is Java able to store 0xff000000 as an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319199/why-is-java-able-to-store-0xff000000-as-an-int)

Comment: Those github links are broken. :/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want INT_MIN value and you are talking about a 4 bytes integer, and since no one has mentioned it before, you can just write:

```
println(0x7FFFFFFF.inv())
```

The neg operand `~` (.inv()) will automatically switch bits from 1 to 0 (which is what happens when you [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)).